# What is the record for the most number of runouts in a Test match?

Tags: cricket, trivia, records

In the 2nd India vs South Africa Test, 2018, there were 5 runouts, is this the record or close to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Record for the most number of run outs in a test match is **7** in [2nd Test, Pakistan tour of Australia at Melbourne, Dec 29 1972 - Jan 3 1973](http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/17242/scorecard/63095/australia-vs-pakistan-2nd-test-pakistan-tour-of-australia-1972-73/):

From [stats.espncricinfo](http://stats.espncricinfo.com/wi/content/records/282828.html) "Most batsmen run out in a match":

[image: record]